# C# Gridview: Setting Up AutoGenerateEditButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

all. I'm having a problem getting the GridView.AutoGenerateEditButton property to do anything for me. Right now, I set it to true, and I don't even get the button added to my GridView, so obviously I can't even get any further to code the actual events. Here is what I have so far (sorry for the messy code; I'm getting close to my deadline and it's been a bit frantic):

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt1 = ds1.Tables.Add("Specs 1");
    if (dt1.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        ds1.Tables["Specs 1"].Columns.Add("General Information");
        ds1.Tables["Specs 1"].Columns.Add("Customer Name");
        ds1.Tables["Specs 1"].Columns.Add("Address");
        // etc.
    }
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        DataRow newRow = ds1.Tables["Specs 1"].NewRow();
        int x = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn thisColumn in ds1.Tables["Specs 1"].Columns)
        {
            newRow[ds1.Tables["Specs 1"].Columns[x]] = Convert.ToString(dr[x]);
            x += 1;
        }
        ds1.Tables["Specs 1"].Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
    DataSet flipped_ds1 = FlipDataSet(ds1); // Flips the dataset's orientation.
```

Then, when it's time for me to add the GridView to the page, I use the following code:

```
GridView outputGrid1 = new GridView();
outputGrid1.ShowHeader = false; // Remove the integer headings.
outputGrid1.DataSource = flipped_ds1;
outputGrid1.DataBind();
outputGrid1.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;
Controls.Add(outputGrid1);
```

Now, the columns are being added exactly the way that I want, and the data is populating properly. However, I don't have the edit buttons that I assume I should have by setting the GridView.AutoGenerateEditButton property to true. I'm sure I'm missing something simple; can someone help? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the AutoGenerateEditButton before the call to DataBind() ? Is there a way to prevent updates in your DataSet (the introspection may detect it and avoid providing a useless button maybe) ?

Comment: That's all it was. I just needed to declare it before the DataBind. Thanks very much!